# How does Symfony2 UniqueEntity constraint work?

Tags: php, symfony, constraints

First of all, I know how to use a unique constraint in Symfony2. This is more a question about how it works under the hood.

For instance, I have something like this as a constraint:

```
company\TestBundle\Entity\Answer:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [question, rank]
```

And I have a simple form, with one field:

```
class AnswerLabelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('label');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'company\TestBundle\Entity\Answer'
        ));
    }
}
```

What I expected:

- Every time I pick an Answer entity and change either the question attribute or the rank attribute, it will check that the new couple of values question/rank doesn't already exist in database.
- With the above form, verify the unique constraint is useless, (with a notable exception: in case of the creation of a new Answer entity, but let's consider this is not the purpose of this form).

What it seems to do in reality:

- It checks the unique constraint when I use the `handleRequest()` method.

Hey, but neither question nor rank attributes change, so how come?

Moreover, when I looked in the logs, the request to check the constraint looked like this:

```
SELECT a.a, a.b, a.c, ... FROM Answer a WHERE a.question = ? AND a.rank = ?
```

This is a pretty heavy request compared to a simple `SELECT COUNT()...`. `COUNT` should be sufficient, doesn't it?

This is a problem for me, because my project do lots of little updates like the one in the above example, that trigger this non-optimized behavior.

Did I misunderstand something? Can I change this behavior?

Comment: By default the constraint will always be applied.  The validator has no way of knowing if the values changed.  What you can do is to conditionally apply the constraint based in a validation group.  You then tell the form which groups to use so you can have individual create/update forms.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups

Comment: @Cerad Yes, thanks. Validation groups solve the problem. But I'm still wondering about the SQL request. Is retrieving the whole object needed? Why not just a COUNT request?

Comment: Clone the existing constraint then write you own sql.  Be a bit of a schock if performance actually improves.  Micro-optimizations such as these seldom help.  But understanding how to write you own constraints will prove useful.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html